# Embedding static Google Earth Engine JavaScript in web page?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, google-earth-engine

I have made a couple informational views in Google Earth Engine code editor and would like to put the resulting static map in a webpage.

I am a novice at html, but have experience embedding mapbox and leaflet maps in pages.

Comment: There is an easy answer here which is to use `Export.map.toCloudStorage()`, but the question has been locked.

Comment: you rock....thanks!  also read a post on another channel how to export a "static" map to html....

Comment: If the question is changed by @RobWade to refer to a "static" map instead of "live map" I think we should reopen it and convert Nicholas comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @NicholasClinton:

> There is an easy answer here which is to use `Export.map.toCloudStorage()`